# Graphical solution?

Tags: voltage, resistors

I have the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

where \$R_{G2} = 4.7\mbox{ }k\Omega\$

I need to find the operating point that produces maximum gain. Then I have to find \$V_G\$ graphically. At the end I have to find the value of \$R_{G1}\$ that will produce the maximum gain.

I am not asking for a solution (this is homework) but is this even possible? I mean is it possible to find \$V_G\$ from a graph?

Comment: Dumping a 2400 x 1600 pixel picture on us right out of your camera is ridiculous.  I shrunk it to 600 x 400 and evrything is still quite readable.  Now, why couldn't you do that in the first place!?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I am sorry about that but i thought it wasn't a problem as the site shrinks the image to fit the post.

Comment: It is possible. I'll give you a hint - when you plot two lines on a graph, it's the same as solving two simultaneous equations. The crossing point is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very much possible. This following method required that you know \$K_n\$ and \$V_{tn}\$ of the FET.

Here is the load line of this amplifier:

[image]

Now for maximum gain you want maximum symetrical output swing. This is achieved by biasing the FET so that the Q-point is in the centre of the load line as shown above. To get to the centre of the load line you first need to find \$V_{DS(sat)}\$

At the \$V_{DS(sat)}\$ point we know that:
$$
I_{DT} = K_n(V_{GSt}-V_{TN})^2 
= K_nV_{DS(sat)}^2
$$

Because \$V_{DS(sat)}=V_{GSt}-V_{TN}\$

Now from the equation of the load line:
$$
I_{DT} = \frac{V_{DD}-V_{DS(sat)}}{R_D} = K_nV_{DS(sat)}^2
$$

Solving this quadratic equation, you will get two values for \$V_{DS(sat)}\$. One should be obviously wrong (such as a negative value) and should be discarded.

You can now calculate the Q point \$V_{DSQ}\$ and \$I_{DQ}\$:

For \$V_{DSQ}\$ to lie in the middle of the saturation region it should be valid that:
$$
V_{DSQ}-V_{DS(sat)}=V_{DD}-V_{DSQ}
$$
So:
$$
V_{DSQ} = \frac{V_{DS(sat)}+V_{DD}}{2}
$$

With \$V_{DSQ}\$ known you can calculate \$I_{DQ}\$:
$$
I_{DQ} = \frac{V_{DD}-V_{DSQ}}{R_D}
$$

Now for the good stuff:
$$
I_{DQ} = K_n(V_{GSQ}-V_{TN})^2
$$
$$
V_{GSQ} = \sqrt{\frac{I_{DQ}}{K_n}}+V_{TN}
$$

Now you have solved it. Because there is no source resistor, \$V_G = V_{GSQ}\$

For the resistor biasing network it is simply:
$$
V_{GSQ} = \frac{R_{G2}}{R_{G1}+R_{G2}}V_{DD}
$$

And you can solve your resistor values from there.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum gain should be close to where Rd and the FET drop the same voltage, which is apparently 3.5V each in your case.  3.5V / Rd will give you the current.  From the FET datasheet you can probably get a rough idea what Vg needs to be to allow that current at that voltage, then calculate Rg1 to produce that voltage.